# - Failed: "port" option should be >= 0 and < 65536: 500000

Tags: angular, protractor

I am testing my app with protractor and I searched in internet and tried many things to solve it but it doesn't work. My Angular CLI 6 application runs at port 4200.

Here is my protractor.config:

```
const SpecReporter = require('jasmine-spec-reporter').SpecReporter;

exports.config = {
  allScriptsTimeout: 11000,
  specs: [
    './src/**/*.e2e-spec.ts'
  ],
  capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome'
  },
  chromeOnly: true,
  directConnect: true,
  baseUrl: 'http://localhost:4200/',
  //seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub/',
  framework: 'jasmine',
  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    showColors: true,
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000,
    print: function () {}
  },
  onPrepare() {
    require('ts-node').register({
      project: require('path').join(__dirname, './tsconfig.e2e.json')
    });



  let browserName = browser.getCapabilities().then((c) => {
    return c.get('browserName').replace(/ /g, "_");
  });
  console.log(browserName);


    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new SpecReporter({
      spec: {
        displayStacktrace: true
      }
    }));
  }
};
```

> - Failed: "port" option should be >= 0 and < 65536: 500000
>           at lookupAndConnect (net.js:1064:13)
>           at Socket.connect (net.js:1037:5)
>           at Object.connect (net.js:113:35)
>           at DebugHelper.validatePortAvailability_ (/Users/Picchu/Documents/shortener/node_modules/protractor/built/debugger.js:204:26)
>           at flow.execute (/Users/Picchu/Documents/shortener/node_modules/protractor/built/debugger.js:61:18)
>           at TaskQueue.execute_ (/Users/Picchu/Documents/shortener/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:3084:14)
>           at TaskQueue.executeNext_ (/Users/Picchu/Documents/shortener/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:3067:27)
>           at asyncRun (/Users/Picchu/Documents/shortener/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2927:27)
>           at /Users/Picchu/Documents/shortener/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:668:7
>           at 
>       From: Task: debugging tasks
>           at DebugHelper.init_ (/Users/Picchu/Documents/shortener/node_modules/protractor/built/debugger.js:59:35)
>           at DebugHelper.init (/Users/Picchu/Documents/shortener/node_modules/protractor/built/debugger.js:17:14)
>           at ProtractorBrowser.pause (/Users/Picchu/Documents/shortener/node_modules/protractor/built/browser.js:949:26)
>           at UserContext. (/Users/Picchu/Documents/shortener/e2e/src/app.e2e-spec.ts:16:13)
>           at /Users/Picchu/Documents/shortener/node_modules/jasminewd2/index.js:112:25
>           at new ManagedPromise (/Users/Picchu/Documents/shortener/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:1077:7)
>           at ControlFlow.promise (/Users/Picchu/Documents/shortener/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2505:12)
>           at schedulerExecute (/Users/Picchu/Documents/shortener/node_modules/jasminewd2/index.js:95:18)
>           at TaskQueue.execute_ (/Users/Picchu/Documents/shortener/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:3084:14)
>           at TaskQueue.executeNext_ (/Users/Picchu/Documents/shortener/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:3067:27)
>       From: Task: Run it("should display welcome message") in control flow
>           at UserContext. (/Users/Picchu/Documents/shortener/node_modules/jasminewd2/index.js:94:19)
>           at /Users/Picchu/Documents/shortener/node_modules/jasminewd2/index.js:64:48
>           at ControlFlow.emit (/Users/Picchu/Documents/shortener/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/events.js:62:21)
>           at ControlFlow.shutdown_ (/Users/Picchu/Documents/shortener/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2674:10)
>           at shutdownTask_.MicroTask (/Users/Picchu/Documents/shortener/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2599:53)
>       From asynchronous test:
>       Error
>           at Suite. (/Users/Picchu/Documents/shortener/e2e/src/app.e2e-spec.ts:13:3)
>           at Object. (/Users/Picchu/Documents/shortener/e2e/src/app.e2e-spec.ts:5:1)
>           at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
>           at Module.m._compile (/Users/Picchu/Documents/shortener/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:400:23)
>           at Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
>           at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .ts] (/Users/Picchu/Documents/shortener/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:403:12)
>
> ---
>
> - Failures                    *
>
>   ---
>
> 1) workspace-project App should display welcome message
>     - Failed: "port" option should be >= 0 and < 65536: 500000
>
> Executed 1 of 1 spec (1 FAILED) in 2 secs. [07:02:20] I/launcher - 0
>   instance(s) of WebDriver still running [07:02:20] I/launcher - chrome
>
> ## 01 failed 1 test(s) [07:02:20] I/launcher - overall: 1 failed spec(s) [07:02:20] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 1 An unexpected
>
> error occured: undefined

**UPDATE**

If I set directConnect:false then I am getting following error:

> [17:01:34] I/update - chromedriver: file exists
>   /Users/Picchu/Documents/shortener/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/chromedriver_2.41.zip
>   [17:01:34] I/update - chromedriver: unzipping chromedriver_2.41.zip
>   [17:01:34] I/update - chromedriver: setting permissions to 0755 for
>   /Users/Picchu/Documents/shortener/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/chromedriver_2.41
>   [17:01:34] I/update - chromedriver: chromedriver_2.41 up to date
>   [17:01:35] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver [17:01:35]
>   E/local - Error code: 135 [17:01:35] E/local - Error message: No
>   update-config.json found. Run 'webdriver-manager update' to download
>   binaries. [17:01:35] E/local - Error: No update-config.json found. Run
>   'webdriver-manager update' to download binaries.

**SOLUTION**

The browser.wait() part occurred the error. After I deleted and replaced with browser.sleep() it is working now.

Comment: did you try with direct connect?

Comment: did that work when you ran without direct connect?

Comment: I have set directConnect: true and I tried both false and true. If I set it to false then I am getting diferent error: Error message: No update-config.json found.